# Why does closing a form invoke Window_Closing() method?

Tags: c#

I am not sure why, but when I call the close() method on a form, it automatically calls Window_Closing() method, but why?

I traced the code, and indeed it automatically calls it, but I'm unsure.

Relevant snippet of code (from a book called Visual C# 2010 Step by Step):

```
namespace BellRingers
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string[] towers = { "Great Shevington", "Little Mudford", 
                                      "Upper Gumtree", "Downley Hatch" };
        private string[] ringingMethods = { "Plain Bob", "Reverse Canterbury", 
                                          "Grandsire", "Stedman", "Kent Treble Bob", "Old Oxford Delight",
                                          "Winchendon Place", "Norwich Surprise", "Crayford Little Court"};



        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxResult key = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit",
                "Confirm",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                MessageBoxImage.Question,
                MessageBoxResult.No);
            e.Cancel = (key == MessageBoxResult.No);
        }

        private void exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, this is what `Window_Closing` method is for. To be called when the window is closed, no matter how.

Comment: When you call `Close` method, it will rise `OnClosing` event and then `OnClosed`. This is intended. What you can do is to add some `bool` flag to check in `Closing` (or see `e.CloseReason`) whenever it was closed by the user or by exit button.

Comment: What was your expectation and why? The `window` is... `closing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is what Closing is there for. The framework raises the `Closing` event whenever the `Close()` method is called on the form.

The following snippet from MSDN explains when Closing is raised and when it is not.

From MSDN:

> Closing can be handled to detect when a window is being closed (for example, when Close is called). Furthermore, Closing can be used to prevent a window from closing. To prevent a window from closing, you can set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs argument to true.
>
> The Closing event is raised when Close is called, if a window's Close button is clicked, or if the user presses ALT+F4.
>
> If an owned window was opened by its owner window using Show, and the owner window is closed, the owned window's Closing event is not raised. If the owner of a window is closed (see Owner), Closing is not raised on the owned window.
>
> If Shutdown is called, the Closing event for each window is raised. However, if Closing is canceled, cancellation is ignored.
>
> If a session ends because a user logs off or shuts down, Closing is not raised; handle SessionEnding to implement code that cancels application closure.
>
> If you want to show and hide a window multiple times during the lifetime of an application, and you don't want to reinstantiate the window each time you show it, you can handle the Closing event, cancel it, and call the Hide method. Then, you can call Show on the same instance to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It wasn't quite clear to me that, it was a built in method that automatically gets called.

Comment: @standbyfor You misunderstood - it's not a built-in method, it's a built-in event. You write the event handler yourself, and the `Window` class executes all the event handlers of the given event, in your case, `Closing`. Have a look at what events are, it's a pretty useful concept.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the whole point of the Closing event. If you're talking about where the wiring is that assigns the method to the relevant event, that'd usually be in the form designer. Although I do know that events can be bound automatically by name in e.g. ASP.NET, so if there's nowhere the event is bound manually, it might be that it has been bound based on name.

Most likely it's in the designer, though.

Comment: That is the thing, I wasn't sure when and how it is bound. Is there some hiearchy or something.